# Append dynamic content to a unordered list with jQuery / apex

Tags: jquery, html, apex-code

I have an unordered list of contacts which populates dynamically from my db when the page loads. I create new contacts and add them to this list with the function below.

```
    function addContactToList(){    
        api.implementListAdd('{!userId}', contactInfo, function(){}, function(){}, function(){} );
    }
```

The problem is, the contact doesn't appear until I refresh the page. How can I add it to the list dynamically?

Here's the html and apex code for the list

```
    <ul data-role="listview" id="sortedList">   
        <apex:repeat value="{! myContacts }" var="contact">
            <li>
               <a href="" class="">
                    <div class="">
                          <span class="name">Name</span><span class="value">{! contact.lastname }</span><br></br>
                    </div>
                </a>
           </li>    
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
```

Would something like this work? This doesnt, but am I on the right track?

```
    function addContactToList(){    
        var newContact = api.implementListAdd('{!userId}', contactInfo, function(){}, function(){}, function(){} );
        jQuery('#sortedList').append("<ui><li>"+newContact+"</li></ui>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.

```
jQuery('#sortedList').append('<li><a href="" class=""><div class=""><span lass="name">'+newContact['Name']+'</span><span class="value">'+newContact['lastname']+'</span><br></br></div> </a></li>');
```